# Should I treat dependent variable as continuous or categorical?

Tags: r, machine-learning, probability, random-forest

I'm trying to use RF (Random Forest) in R in order to predict if the *Titanic* passengers will perish or not. Thus, the nature of my dependent variable is categorical.

I would like to predict the probability of each passenger perish. So, with this outcome I can clusterize and make groups, like this:

group A: passengers who have [81 to 100] % of perish risk .
group B:  passengers who have [60 to 80] % of perish risk.
group C: passengers who have <60 % of perish risk.

So, if the *Titanic* happens again, I could know the probability of each passengers perished and which group he belongs to ( A, B or C ).

However, I don't know what is the best approach to get the probability of a passenger perish. I can transform my dependent variable to a continuous one,and then, use RF to get the probability of a passenger perish ( 0 to 1), or I can use the RF with dependent variable as categorical one and use the probability to perform this.

Comment: What's "RF"? What's "de"?

Comment: The goal should not be to define completely arbitrary risk groups but rather to estimate risk.

Comment: What's "theat" in your title?

Comment: Personal I understand the predicted risk as the 'perish probability' for a given passenger if the Titanic ship repetitively would sink again and again. That is very arbitrary to me :) Would that be correctly understood?

Comment: Yes. that is it. I would like to know the perish probability, in order to make groups based in this probability.

Comment: ...and what is your motive to aggregate in groups? (a) Communication: "Top 1% has as much money as the 99%", (B) Implementation: "We will only make those bets having a minimum x probability of winning".

Comment: Logistic regression is the gold standard for this type of dataset.  And there is no such thing as an intrinsic risk.  We can still define risk on an event that can never recur by being Bayesian and considering degree of belief.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend categorical. RF can generate pseudo probabilistic predictions defined as vote ratios for each sample for each target class. From such predictions you could generate arbitrary risk groups if really needed for some specific reason. Remember only to use cross-validated predictions. In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440272/binary-classification-or-unknown-class-in-random-forest-in-r/32456040#32456040) is shown how to extract probabilistic predictions for the iris data set.

Trevor Stephens fine [tutorial](http://trevorstephens.com/post/72916401642/titanic-getting-started-with-r) demonstrates that a rather naive RF model performs pretty poorly on the titanic data set. He also shows how to improve such an RF model to make it a top tier in the Kaggle tutorial competition.